# Creating custom tasksel recipes

Tags: server, tasksel

I'd like to create custom tasks for `tasksel` - is there any way to do this, like creating a package for Ubuntu, only it's for tasksel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tasksel just reads data from `/usr/share/tasksel/*.desc` and `/usr/local/share/tasksel/*.desc`.

If you look at those files, you'll see that they have a yaml-like file with lists of packages and sections/descriptions.

So just put a file in `/usr/local/share/tasksel/yourtasks.desc` .. or create a .deb that puts a file in `/usr/share/tasksel/yourtasks.desc`. If you think it might be useful to the greater community, I'd suggest submitting it as a feature request here:

http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+filebug