# Tasksel task versioning

Tags: 16.04, lamp, tasksel

I need to install the LAMP stack for one of our projects, in which machines are powered by Xubuntu. I'm looking for the fastest way we could have that installed and I have discovered [tasksel](https://askubuntu.com/a/211916/171672).

Now I would like to know if I could somehow guarantee immutability for task results. As an example, running `sudo tasksel install lamp-server` nowadays installs mysql-server 5.7, php 7.0, apache 2.4...

What would the output for this command be in the future? If the task gets updated and changes some major versions for the applications involved, it might break the integration with my application (introducing mysql-server 8, as an example).

Is there any way to version default tasks or do I need to [write my own recipe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35797/creating-custom-tasksel-recipes)?